# Where can I access caniuse.com browser support tables offline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, offline

Is there a way to access data of a website [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) being offline? Or any other resources regarding browser compatibility. Something similar to [devdocs.io](http://devdocs.io/) or Zeal/Dash offline documentation browsers.

Comment: A local install of a database can do this.

Comment: @bash0r Yeah but does http://caniuse.com/ have a public downloadable database?

Comment: @MarshalBanana: Whatever that service is, you'd have to ask them.

Comment: You should rewrite your question to make this clearer. I don't know if this particular software is available for offline use. I guess it's not. And David is right. You should consider asking them not a broad community that is not related to this particular service.

Comment: @bash0r: I guess if you don't know the answer you probably shouldn't complain that the question is badly formed) But thanks anyway guys, maybe someone else knows. If not, i'll try to ask the service.

Comment: @MarshalBanana There are several guide lines on how to post a question on here. Your question definitely breaks these guide lines. So don't complain about me complaining about your badly formed question...

Comment: @bash0r: Ok, sorry for that. I didn't actually complain) Can you please share a link to those guide lines? When i posted this question i thought i satisfied all the requirements around the post form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) browser support tables is now available in [devdocs.io](https://devdocs.io) webapp, which support offline access.

Answer (score 0):

**A.** You can download caniuse.com database from GitHub, at https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse

Digging in JSON files might not be the most efficient way, but having database, you can make your own app. If you do make one, don't forget to share it ;)

**B.** You can also visit http://caniuse.com/#tables and click "Show all" button on the bottom of the page, than `Ctrl+S` it.

**C.** Alternative: http://sheet.shiar.nl/browser. Just save as complete website, like with solution B.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is definitely a starting point. I'll mark your answer as a solution a bit later in case some more information will come ;)

Comment: Consider changing question title to something like: "Where can I access browser support data offline?" and adding tags like `html`, `html5`, `css`. It's a good question, so don't be disappointed it got downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Actually, at first I thought it would be fun, a bit of humor in the title, a bit of wordplay) But as it turns out it's not how it works on stackoverflow. I should deal with it) Also i found a [DevDocs's Trello board](https://trello.com/b/6BmTulfx/devdocs-documentation) and posted a suggestion there https://trello.com/c/PVnfdeaN/26-suggest-new-docs-here. But i think it's maybe not possible to implement in context of devdocs environment. Anyway thanks to you suggestion, i found a corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1756). So thanks a lot!